# Python interpreters and Alias's

Tags: python

Is there any mechanism similar to alias's (with something like BASH) that can be used in Ipython or the Python Interpreter?

For instance if I find myself frequently doing something like:

```
var = urllib2.urlopen('http://programmers.stackexchange.com')
```

But I don't want to continually type out those strings.

Is there any method of (Persistently between exits) shortening the request other than writing a script for it?

Answer (score 1):

No, but in your interpreter, write this:

```
def pse_url():
    global var
    var = urllib2.urlopen('http://programmers.stackexchange.com')
```

Then, write `pse_url()` whenever you need to affect your variable.
It would be cleaner to not use a global variable:

```
var = pse_url()
```

If you have many such utilities, put them  in your own module and load them once when you start the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is for such one line expressions you can create lambdas functions ( and functions for bigger one as **@coredump** suggested), see code below:

```
se_open = (lambda: urllib2.urlopen('http://programmers.stackexchange.com'))
so_open = (lambda: urllib2.urlopen('http://programmers.stackexchange.com'))
```

Know if you have to create new var you have to simply run command:

```
var_se = se_open()
var_so = so_open()
```

Also you can create script which contains all thst shortcuts and start python with imported script by command:

```
$ python -i script.py
```

All functions defined in `script.py` would be available in your REPL.